# Can i upload a file using C# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, upload

I have this code :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#openDocumentsSelector")]
private IWebElement BTNOpenDocumentsSelector { get; set; }
public void AddNewFile(DocumentsTestValues new_upload)
{                  
    this.BTNOpenDocumentsSelector.SendKeys("TestUploadDocument.txt");
}
```

And i get this error:

> unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: you want to send the full path of the file to the form's <input type='file'> tag.  That will fill the path as the "value" attribute.  Then submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that button is visible on the screen,
   has visible style and does not hide by any other element.
   If not - try to scroll view to the button position.
2. Also, your link can be obsolete at the moment of sending keys, try to refresh (just try to find and select it again).
3. And also like said @pcalkins try to use the full path to the file.